# Google apps script date doesn't exist! Using formatdate

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a vaguely amusing problem, where I'm trying to get a date output with the following line:

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("G2:G2").getValue(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "DD.MM.YY");
```

The problem is, when I call 'date', the day is simply a continuation from the first day of the year. For example, today (05.02.14 in my format) comes out as 36.02.14 - a day that doesn't exist! Obviously in January I hadn't noticed the issue.

I must be missing something, I'd be grateful to find out what...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formatDate pattern is case sensitive.
d -> day (lower case)
M -> month (upper case)
y -> year (lower case)
Try this:

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("G2:G2").getValue(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd.MM.yy");
```